# creating a 2D circle plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

#I need to create a visualization that plots a bunch of 2D circles using matplot and make sure that they don't overlap. I want the user to be able to put in a certain radius and have the program fill up the plot with as many circles as it can wihtout it asking for how many circles the user wants like what i have now. Just not sure how to get the program to automatically fill up the plot until it can't anymore.

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius

def distance(circle1, circle2):
     return math.sqrt((circle1.x - circle2.x)**2 + (circle1.y - circle2.y)**2)

def check_overlap(circle, circles):
    for c in circles:
        if distance(circle, c) < circle.radius + c.radius:
            return True
    return False

def generate_random_circle(radius, width, height, circles):
    while True:
        x = random.randint(radius, width - radius)
        y = random.randint(radius, height - radius)
        new_circle = Circle(x, y, radius)
        if not check_overlap(new_circle, circles):
            return new_circle

def main():
    width = 500  # Width of the canvas
    height = 500  # Height of the canvas
    radius = int(input("Enter the radius of the circles: "))
    num_circles = int(input("Enter the number of circles: "))

    circles = []
    for _ in range(num_circles):
        circle = generate_random_circle(radius, width, height, circles)
        circles.append(circle)

    # Plotting the circles
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for circle in circles:
        ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((circle.x, circle.y), radius=circle.radius,     color='blue', alpha=0.5))

    # Set axis limits and aspect ratio
    ax.set_xlim(0, width)
    ax.set_ylim(0, height)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

    # Display the plot
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Instead of doing `while True`, you can ask the user to enter the maximum number of iterations (you can call it something like `maxiter`) before it gives up. If `maxiter` is reached, you can assume that the field has been filled up.